# Gratitude and Affection

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, social-neuroscience

1. If a person X has gratitude towards person Y, will that cause bias of affection for X towards Y ?
2. Can there be a case that X tend to be more affectionate to a person Z to whom X has less gratitude comparatively to that of Y ?
3. Is it common that gratitude perceived to be affection ?